# Why is $ \mathbb{K}[X] \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \mathbb{K}[Y] \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}[X \times Y] $ surjective?

Tags: tensor-products, affine-varieties

I am studying products in the category of affine varieties and I don't know how to prove that the map

$ \mathbb{K}[X] \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \mathbb{K}[Y] \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}[X \times Y], $

where $X$ is a affine variety and $ \mathbb{K}[X]$ is the ring of regular function on $X$, is surjective.

I know that if $W \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ is a closed subset then $ \mathbb{K}[W] \simeq \mathbb{K}[z_1, \dots,z_n]/I(W)$ but I can't link the two results.

Have you any hints?

Comment: Can you prove it for the simple case that $X = Y = {\mathbb A}^1$? Then ${\mathbb K}[X]$, ${\mathbb K}[Y]$ and ${\mathbb K}[X \times Y]$ are just polynomial rings (in 1, 1 and 2 variables).

Comment: @Magdiragdag so I don't need to use the isomorphism $\mathbb{K}[X] \simeq \mathbb{K}[z_1,\dots,z_n]/I(X)$ nor the universal property of tensor products?

Comment: You do use both, but in an easier setting. For $X = {\mathbb A}^1$, $K[X] = K[x]/(0) = K[x]$ and you do need the universal property of tensor products (or an explicit construction of the tensor product) to prove that $K[x] \otimes_K K[y] = K[x,y]$.

Comment: You might want to have a look at section 2.4 in Humphrey’s *Linear algebraic groups*.